# samsung duos s7562 how to see/browse contents of sd card

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, sd-card, file-management

How can I see/browse the contents of my sdcard on my new and shiny samsung duos GT-s7562?

android ver = 4.0.4

Answer (score 1):

You have to use File Manager program. I think Samsung Mobile comes with one already instaleed. If not install apps like [ES File Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop&hl=en)

[image]